# The OnChange function do not work after having disabled the Select

Tags: javascript, html, select, onchange

I have an example with 2 selects. Once you change something in the first one, the 2nd (which is disabled) should change to enabled. To there I have no problems. The thing is that when you change something in the 2nd **a webpage should open**. That works fine when I don't have the .disabled assigned to the "var urlmenu2" but isn't working when it is. Anyone know what can be happening?

Here's the HTML code:

```
<select id="menu1" >

<option value="0" selected="selected" id="selected"> Select an option </option>
  <optgroup label="Category1:">
  <option value="1"> Option1 </option>
  <option value="2"> Option2 </option>
  <option value="3"> Option3 </option>
  <option value="4"> Option4 </option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="Category2:">
  <option value="5"> Option5 </option>
  <option value="6"> Option6 </option> 
  <option value="7"> Option7 </option>
  <option value="8"> Option8 </option>
  <option value="9"> Option9 </option>
  <option value="10"> Option10 </option>
  <option value="11"> Option11 </option>
  <option value="12"> Option12 </option>
  <option value="13"> Option13 </option>
  <option value="14"> Option14 </option>

<optgroup label="Category3:">
  <option value="15"> Option15 </option>
</optgroup>

</select>

<select id="menu2">
  <option value="0" selected="selected" id="selected2"> Select an option </option>
  <option value="1" id="center">Home</option>
  <option value="2" id="home">In the Center</option>
</select>
```

and here's the Javascript code:

```
 var urlmenu1 = document.getElementById('menu1');
 **var urlmenu2 = document.getElementById('menu2').disabled=true;**

urlmenu1.onchange = function change1(){

    if(urlmenu1.selectedIndex != 0){    
        **var urlmenu2 = document.getElementById('menu2').disabled=false;**
        var selected = document.getElementById('selected').disabled=true;
    }

    if(urlmenu1.selectedIndex >= 1 && urlmenu1.selectedIndex <= 4) {
         var opcion = document.getElementById('casa').disabled=false;
         var seleccionado2 = document.getElementById('selected2').disabled=true;
    } 

    if(urlmenu1.selectedIndex >= 6 && urlmenu1.selectedIndex <= 15){
         var opcion = document.getElementById('home').disabled=true;
         var selected2 = document.getElementById('selected2').disabled=true;
    } 

};

 urlmenu2.onchange = function cahnge2(){

    if(urlmenu1.selectedIndex == 1 && urlmenu2.selectedIndex==1){
        window.open("http://www.google.com",'_self');
        urlmenu1.selectedIndex = 0;
        urlmenu2.selectedIndex = 0;
    } 
     if(urlmenu1.selectedIndex == 2 && urlmenu2.selectedIndex==1){
        window.open("http://www.yahoo.com",'_self');
        urlmenu1.selectedIndex = 0;
        urlmenu2.selectedIndex = 0;
    } 

 etc... until 15
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you disable a field the functionality disables too. Try triggering change event manually.

```
 urlmenu2.change();
 urlmenu2.onchange = function() ....
```

Comment: Hey Marcos, thanks for answering so fast, I tried but it gets still disabled. Any more idea?

Comment: If you make the trigger `change()` must works, but disabled property doesn't removes. Please, show us how do you are making it

Comment: I just added the "urlmenu2.change();" before the 2nd function as you suggested, maybe you mean something else with the trigger? I am not used to that :/

Comment: The trigger is for fire the event manually. If you make a `element.trigger("change")` (jquery) or `element.change()` (javascript) the event fires even when element is disabled. So you put it when you need to fire event.

Comment: After having read a lot about it and your explanation I think I understood how does it works, I tried to use it in the next example below but I don't know if I did it properly cause it's not working at all :S

Answer (score 0):

I ended solving the issue by configuring the html code like:
    **select** id="menu2" **disabled="true"**                             I wrote *true* instead of *disabled* as was commented in many websites.

Now a new problem appeared. Depending on the value of the change I do in the first select I want to disable the option "casa" from the 2nd select or activate it. Incredibly it has no problems to disable correctly the "var seleccionado" but with the other vars: seleccionado2 or casita it doesn't works. What do you think it can be the problem? I tried even to force it triggering as you comented Marcos if you see "urlmenu1.onchange(casita.disabled=false);" but I am not achieving it.

Thank you. Here the code:

```
 var urlmenu1 = document.getElementById('menu1');
 var urlmenu2 = document.getElementById('menu2');
 var desbloqueo = document.getElementById('bloqueo');
 var casita = document.getElementById('casa');

urlmenu1.onchange = function change1(){

    if(urlmenu1.selectedIndex !==0){    
        var urlmenu2 = document.getElementById('menu2').disabled=false;
        var seleccionado = document.getElementById('selected').disabled=true;
        desbloqueo.style.display ='none';
    }

    if(urlmenu1.selectedIndex >= 1 && urlmenu1.selectedIndex <= 4) {
         var seleccionado2 = document.getElementById('selected2').disabled=true;
          urlmenu1.onchange(casita.disabled=false);
    } 

    if(urlmenu1.selectedIndex >= 6 && urlmenu1.selectedIndex <= 15){
         urlmenu1.onchange(casita.disabled=true);
         var seleccionado2 = document.getElementById('selected2').disabled=true;

    } 

};
```

Comment: Mmmm, I tell you trigger change event, but you are listen change event. Is different `onchange()` than `change()`. `urlmenu1.onchange(function() { casita.disabled = false; });` it listen change event; `urlmenu1.change()`: it triggers change event

Comment: Hum, such a mistake T.T. Although trying it with the .change doesn't results neither. Now I don't know what to do. I tried: casita.change(casita.disable=false); instead of urlmenu1.onchange(...) and although tried with urlmenu2.change(casita.disable=false); but it doesn't change (disable or enable)

Comment: .change() does not any content inside. Only call it element.change() to tell browser that element changes. You need to change the element value dinamically to try another solution

Comment: ok, so no content inside, but then how we tell the machine which change has to be applied? (enable or disable) Would be something like this?  casita.disabled=false;
casita.change();

Comment: Yes. When you make `casita.change();` you are telling to browser that `casita` element was change its value. Disabled property doesn't fires change event. When you make `casita.onchange()` you are listening if the browser fires the change event, but you don't fire it manually. I wish you can solve it, but I don't know in what state you are.

Comment: However, I recommend to you to use jQuery to this tasks. Less code, less problems and makes the cross-browser compatibility more easy.

Comment: Well I wil have to learn jQuery then. However now my intention is to finish this. The casita.disabled=false; (where casita is document.getElementById('casa') casita.change(); is not working (I am putting it all in the 2nd IF). I tried too to put it in a function like:  function casita1(){
     document.getElementById('casa').disabled=false;
    }
    casita1.change(); but still not achieving results :/

Comment: Why don't you open a jsfiddle.com ? I think that I can help you better. Put in there all your code (js, css and html) that is important to this issue and I see it slow and better

Comment: Ok, you're right I just created it take a look! https://jsfiddle.net/59bbkzj4/ I hope you have a big screen cause it's configurated for some resolutions and could overlay itself if you have a small window you will see!

Comment: You are mixing things. If you make a function called `casita1()` you can't call change() method, because change is for elements, not functions. For understanding, this works: `document.getElementById("casita").change();` and this not works: `casita1().change()`. The code that you put in jsfiddle is so long, give me some minutes to read it, but my console at opens throws a `casita1.change() is not a function`, with reason.

Comment: yeah sorry I forgot to change it, was just a trial I have deleted it now. I don't bother to wait.

Comment: I think that you are making a lot of code for a simple question. What do you expect to do exactly? I think that you need to select one option for first select, then select another option of second select and depends of two values launch a window. Is true? When is necessary to disable selects? I don't understand so good that functionality. I think that remaking code with less lines we can made it

Comment: in a chat, you can explain me in spanish ;) [chat] EDIT: You can't, need 20 reputation. But you can explain me here fast

Comment: hum xD ok I was trying to open the chat. El hecho es que no todas las opciones del primer select tienen tratamiento en casa, solo las 4 primeras, así que la intención es desactivar el option "casa" cuando pulsas uno que no sean esas 4 primeras opciones del select1 y activarlo cuando si sea una de esas 4. Sino lo que pasa es que el usuario pulsaria En casa pero no hay pagina para redirigirse allí. Espero que lo entiendas así. Gracias Marcos.

Comment: Vale! Creo que he hecho un fiddle que te puede servir. Fíjate que los dos primeros desactivan y el tercero no. https://jsfiddle.net/wz34qjfx/2

Comment: hum ya veo. La cosa es que desactivas el selector completo, yo solo quiero desactivar un option del select (el de casa) pero que aun se pueda seleccionar el de centros. De aquí mi duda que no se active o desactive.

Comment: Para desactivar sólo el option es muy sencillo, mira http://jsfiddle.net/wz34qjfx/3/

Comment: Por cierto, te dejo aquí una modificación para cuando selecciones una opción del segundo select se abra una url, pero que no lo controles tú con js, sino que le especificas la URL desde el html (data-url): http://jsfiddle.net/wz34qjfx/4/ Con esto tienes la funcionalidad completa creo yo

Comment: Y si te vale, lo pongo como respuesta y me la votas ;)

Comment: Yeps, estaba implementando el código adaptado a mi programa. Ya he conseguido que los options se desactiven sin problemas, un código estupendo, muy limpio! Luego lo que me comentas de los URL no lo puedo aplicar puesto que el cambio lo hago solo con las variables centros o casa, no tengo un listado de options enorme al que pulsarle cada opcion, pero es un codigo interesante también. Sí, ponlo como respuesta definitiva porfavor, muchas gracias por tu ayuda prestada!